# Java write into existing .txt file inside a .jar file

Tags: java, file-io, jar

**I know** that this question is a duplicate of :
1) [Java - Writing to txt in a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937904/java-writing-to-txt-in-a-jar-file)
2) [How to read/write file in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994355/how-to-read-write-file-in-jar)
3) [How can modify/edit a file data which is inside a jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967975/how-can-modify-edit-a-file-data-which-is-inside-a-jar)

But I've read it all and I still not have a concrete answer.

If I have a .jar file with this tree:

```
(dir)META-INF -> MANIFEST.MF

(dir)test -> test.txt
          -> Test.class
```

I can read the .txt file with this code:

```
 public String readFromJARFile(String filename)throws IOException {
           InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
           InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
           String line;
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line);
           }
           br.close();
           isr.close();
           is.close();
           return sb.toString();
}
```

If I need to **write into that .txt file**, can I do it? If yes, *how*? If not, *why*?

Thanks.

Comment: Most of the noted duplicates include a comment or answer along the lines of "don't do that!".  Sounds like a good answer to me.

Comment: Without reading the other answers, I can tell you it's a terrible idea because a jar file is also a zip file. A zip file is not designed to be used as a dynamic filesystem. You probably could make it work (in some cases) with a [FUSE file system](http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/) on linux, but I wouldn't even try. It would be easier to store and access an externalized file (perhaps even generated from the contents of your JAR).

Comment: I understand the part of _"don't do that!"_ , but if I do, what could happen?

Comment: The only working way is to create another jar/zip file with the modified contents and replace the original file with the new one afterwards. This will be a heavy operation if you just want to modify a single entry inside a big jar. But that’s how, e.g. `jar uf …` works.